# An example of vertex transitive graph whose chromatic number and clique number is apart.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Can someone give me an example of graph have the following property?

must have:

the chromatic number and clique number differ more than 2, the more the better.

better have:

1. the fewer size the better
2. vertex transitive
3. it is graph core.

Thanks!

Comment: i basically known only Grötzsch graph graph, but it is too big, i want small graph have the property that the chromatic number and clique number differ more than 2.

Comment: I mean undirected graph

Comment: This is a tricky puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

Take $3$ pentagons. Add an edge between a given vertex and all other vertices belonging to the two other pentagons.

To color a pentagon, you need $3$ colors, so to color this graph, you need exactly $9$ colors, but the clique number equals $6$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the havled cubes $\frac{1}{2}Q_n=\rm{Cay}(\mathbb{Z}_2^{n-1},S)$. For $n\geq4$, the clique number is always $n$. But the chromatic number is usually not $n$ unless $n=2^r$. The minimal counterexample is when $n=5$, in which you have $\chi(\frac{1}{2}Q_5)=8$.